# How do you swap endianness of a binary value made out of smaller independent values

Tags: python, performance, bit-manipulation, endianness, can-bus

I am making a class that reads a DBC file and decodes can messages.

In the BC files there is a selection indicating whether a value within a message frame is big Endian or little Endian.

I am unsure how I should be converting to a big endian integer. Should I reverse the whole message data by every bite or bit or Should I extract the required bits then convert to big Endian. This might be a problem if I need to reverse a value with an odd number of bits.

For example a gear position value that’s 3 bits can’t be converted by swap if bytes.

Here are links to what documents I've been referencing when working this:

- http://socialledge.com/sjsu/index.php/DBC_Format
- http://read.pudn.com/downloads766/ebook/3041455/DBC_File_Format_Documentation.pdf

Comment: Won't you need to swap in bytes because that's how the machine operates on them? While you may extract bits is that really how they'll be transmitted? Wouldn't you just pad?

Comment: Personally I don’t know that much about how a computer manipulates and manages data on a hardware level. I started off assuming I converted the hole data frame then I saw you could have different orders in a frame and now I rabbit hold myself into uncertainty

Comment: [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is the ordering or sequencing of ***bytes***, so you needn't worry about bits. That said (with bytes) you simply reverse the order they occur in so the last one becomes the first, the second one become the second-to-last, etc.

Comment: @martineau ok so then I should just change the 8byte message to big Endian and then extract the necessary bites I need from the can message?

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct.

Comment: Note that all modern common machines have 8 bits per byte. I advise to use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module in Python which has been designed for this purpose.

Comment: Endianess on a CAN bus is a complicated topic. Some architectures indeed reverse the complete message. I.e. not only swap the bytes, but completely reverse the payload. In general, the endianess applies to the complete message, not to the individual signals in the message.

Comment: @JérômeRichard On the contrary, _all_ modern machines have 8 bits per byte. Only dysfunctional legacy DSPs have something else. And if you are writing code for a dysfunctional lecacy DSP in Python, the size of a byte is the least of your problems. More importantly, all bytes in a CAN frame are _guaranteed_ to be 8 bits by the ISO standard for CAN.

Comment: @M.Spiller This is specified by the application layer. CANopen for example, enforces little endian encoding on individual words and allows to store several words in one frame. In what order bytes are stored when received/sent to the bus depends on the CAN controller, not the CPU.

Comment: @Lundin The question is about the DBC files, which describe the application layer of the CAN bus, so yes, this is sepcified by the application layer. In the DBC file each signal transported in the payload can have different endianess. Also the DBC allows to configure byte-endianess and bit-endianess. You can have 3 bits of one byte being an enum stored "left to right" and the remaining 5 bits to be an integer stored "right to left".

Comment: @M.Spiller In that case I don't understand the question. If the file points out where a value is stored, what data it contains and what endianess it got, then what's the problem. Just encode/decode accordingly.

Comment: @Lundin True. I think there is some confusion, because googling "endianess" will mostly give you results about "Intel and Motorola" format, i.e. byte ordering. Same can be seen in the earlier comments here. When trying apply the byte-ordering while decoding a 3-bit bit-endian signal, such questions might arise.

Comment: @M.Spiller It would have be a quite smelly application layer protocol to use endianess-encoded bit-fields however. Sure there's crap like "CAN Kingdom" that works in that way, as well as various poorly-designed OEM protocols. But protocols written by professionals generally stick to whole bytes.

Comment: @Lundin I agree. But the question is about a (generic?) DBC and CAN parser, so all eventualities that are allowed by a DBC file have to be considered. Apart from that the DBC files of the OEMs are 90% automatically generated from network descriptions and the tools do all bells and whistles to fit as much data in and do the parsing as "efficient" as possible. One can find quiet often something like "if Bit 17 is 1, read it and the next 3 bits as an 4-bit integer, if bit 17 is 0, ignore it and interpret the next 16 bits as a string".

Comment: Sorry I haven't replied. I didn't expect much help on this topic but I would like to allow for most, if not all, cases in a DBC file. @M.Spiller I can't seem to find a reference to how you define whether the endianness is bit or byte? Note: im having trouble finding good documentation on DBC file syntax but I edited with what I use

Comment: I was certain before and now not so much

Answer (score 0):

Endianess only makes sense if you know the data type of the contents. An 8 byte CAN frame could for example contain 4 x 16 bit integer numbers, or 2 x 32, or 1 x 64. How to convert to the proper endianess is different in all these cases, if you need to convert at all - this does of course depend on the endianess of your target system. And then of course a CAN frame could be smaller than 8 bytes.

So it doesn't make sense to create some general algorithm for this, each frame has to be encoded/decoded as per the nature of the specified data inside it. You cannot do this unless you know the application layer protocol.

(CAN identifier and CRC are always big endian, but this doesn't affect the payload, and the CAN controller will handle network endianess of these parts of the frame, not the programmer.)